# (missing space in) "today" formatting in Polish using polyglossia

Tags: xetex, datetime, polyglossia

Just discovered TeX few days ago :)

Experimenting a lot now. I am trying to make a template for my thesis (which is going to use quotations and bibliography in a good few languages and some serious math too). XeLaTeX seems to be giving me least problems now (but it was tough at the beginning).

Anyways, I am a bit confused about this missing space between month name and the year in the date for the Polish version of it...

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug?

```
%!TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}                                
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguages{latin,greek,russian,polish,german}

\begin{document}

greek (\textgreek[variant=ancient]{ελληνικά \today}),
russian (\textrussian{русский \today}),
polish (\textpolish{polski \today}),
german (\textgerman{Deutsch \today}),
latin (\textlatin{Latina \today}),

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Great Minimal Working Example, thanks for working that out! One detail (that probably isn’t relevant here): Even for MWEs, don’t use `minimal`; see [Why not use the minimal class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely a bug in the file `gloss-polish.ldf`, where the definition of `\datepolish` is

```
\def\datepolish{%
  \def\today{\number\day\space\ifcase\month\or
      stycznia\or lutego\or marca\or kwietnia\or maja\or czerwca\or
      lipca\or sierpnia\or września\or października\or
      listopada\or grudnia\fi
      \number\year}%
  }
```

and there's a missing space, because the space after `\fi` is ignored by rule.

You can correct it, waiting for an official fix, by adding to your document, after having called the language (with `\setmainlanguage{polish}` or `\setotherlanguage{...,polish,...}`),

```
\def\datepolish{%
  \def\today{\number\day\space\ifcase\month\or
      stycznia\or lutego\or marca\or kwietnia\or maja\or czerwca\or
      lipca\or sierpnia\or września\or października\or
      listopada\or grudnia\fi\space
      \number\year}%
  }
```

Complete example:

```
%!TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}                                
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguages{latin,greek,russian,polish,german}

\def\datepolish{%
  \def\today{\number\day\space\ifcase\month\or
      stycznia\or lutego\or marca\or kwietnia\or maja\or czerwca\or
      lipca\or sierpnia\or września\or października\or
      listopada\or grudnia\fi\space
      \number\year}%
  }

\begin{document}

Greek (\textgreek[variant=ancient]{ελληνικά \today})

Russian (\textrussian{русский \today})

Polish (\textpolish{polski \today})

German (\textgerman{Deutsch \today})

Latin (\textlatin{Latina \today})

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've opened [a issue on the GitHub repository of Polyglossia](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/37)